# Starting or resuming async method/coroutine without awaiting it in Python

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio, coroutine

In JavaScript (and other languages) an `async` function is immediately executed upon its invocation until the first `await` is encountered.
This is not the case in Python. From the [`asyncio` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines):

> Note that simply calling a coroutine will not schedule it to be executed:

I find this very confusing, because my mental model of asynchronous programming is like this:

- **S**etup/Initialization/Queuing of asynchronous task as soon as possible (usually quick and nonblocking)
- **A**synchronous task happens in background
- Do other stuff
- **W**aiting for task to complete as late as possible. Maybe its already completed, so no waiting occurs.

```
| S | AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA | W |
        | S | AAAAAAAAAAAAA | W |
           | S | AAAAAAAAAA | WWWWWW |
```

To reduce waiting time the Setup should be executed as soon as possible.
But if the method is `async` in Python the "Setup" part is not executed by calling the method at all. Only if `await` (or `gather`, etc.) is used is it actually started. That makes it very hard to start a bunch of coroutines and wait for all of them or batches to finish, because if you use `asyncio.gather` they are all started at the very end and at the same time, which can waste a lot of time.

One way to execute the setup part immediately without awaiting the method is this:

```py
async def work():
    print("Setup...")
    await asyncio.sleep(1)

async def main():
    task = asyncio.create_task(work())
    await asyncio.sleep(0)
    # do something else
    await task
```

But that is quite cumbersome (and ugly) and also puts me at the whim of the event loop to actually choose the newly created task and not just swap back to the `main` method or something entirely different.

I managed to come up with this method decorator that immediately executes an async method by using `send(None)` and wraps the `async` method into a normal method that returns an `Awaitable`:

```py
def js_like_await(coro):
    class JSLikeCoroutine:
        def __init__(self, first_return, coro_obj):
            self.first_return = first_return
            self.coro_obj = coro_obj
        def __await__(self):
            try:
                yield self.first_return
                while True:
                    yield self.coro_obj.send(None)
            except StopIteration as e:
                return e.value
    def coroutine_with_js_like_await(*args, **kwargs):
        coro_obj = coro(*args, **kwargs)
        first_return = None
        try:
            first_return = coro_obj.send(None)
            return JSLikeCoroutine(first_return, coro_obj)
        except StopIteration as e:
            result = asyncio.Future()
            result.set_result(e.value)
            return result
        
    return coroutine_with_js_like_await
```

But for this to have an effect it would also have to wrap possible inner asynchronous function calls as well, which might not be modifiable for outside callers of the method.

I thought I could make this a lot simpler if there was a way to "attempt" a coroutine to start or resume it.
So switching control flow to the coroutine (similar to what `send()` does), but only if the async function is currently not waiting for something. Returning immediately, if it does.

So I want a method `attempt` that can be used like this to control the execution flow:

```py
def attempt(task):
    while not task.is_waiting:
        task.continue_to_next_await()

async def work():
    print("Setup")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("After first sleep")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Done")
    return "Result"

task = work()  # Nothing is printed, because the coroutine is only created.
attempt(task)  # "Setup" is printed and method returns immediately
attempt(task)  # Nothing happens, because task is still sleeping
time.sleep(15) # Block CPU to wait for sleeping to finish
attempt(task)  # "After first sleep" is printed, because the sleep time is over
attempt(task)  # Nothing happens, because task is still sleeping
time.sleep(15) # Block CPU to wait for second sleeping to finish
attempt(task)  # "Done" is printed.
attempt(task)  # Nothing happens, because task is finished
r = await task # Get result.
```

Is there a way to achieve something like this?

I couldn't get `send(None)` to work multiple times, because after the second `send` it crashes with [`await wasn't used with future`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/d05a180350fe20d5fde56c7e525e394a0b282703/Modules/_asynciomodule.c#L1626) if i discard the Futures that are returned from `send(None)`:

```py
async def work():
    print("Setup")
    await asyncio.sleep(10)
    print("Done")

async def main():
    task = work()
    _ = task.send(None) # Returns <Future pending> of type <class '_asyncio.Future'>
    _ = task.send(None) # RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
```

I feel like I have to somehow give the returned Future back to the event loop, but I don't know how. If I make `attempt` an `__await__`-object that just `yield`s the `Future` from `send` and `await` it, it will wait for the `sleep` and the `attempt` becomes blocking.

<sub>Note, that I'm aware of the obvious solution of "not make your method `async`". But sadly, it is too late, to make everyone adhere to that.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the functionality that you are trying to code in the last example is mix of an asynchronous generator https://peps.python.org/pep-0525/ and running a coroutine in parallel on an event loop in another thread https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe .
While it is doable, you might want to consider a different pattern.

## Using run_coroutine_threadsafe

### Code

```py
import asyncio
import time
from threading import Thread

global_loop = None

def thread_for_event_loop():
    global global_loop
    global_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(global_loop)
    global_loop.run_forever()

t = Thread(target=thread_for_event_loop)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
time.sleep(1) # wait for thread to start

old_print = print
print = lambda *_: old_print(round(time.perf_counter(), 1), *_)

def attempt(future): # doesn't actually do anything, only prints if task is done
    print(future.done())
    

async def work():
    print("SETUP")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("MIDDLE")
    await asyncio.sleep(2)
    print("END")
    return "Result"

async def main():
    print("START", int(time.perf_counter()))
    task = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(work(), global_loop)
    attempt(task)
    attempt(task)
    print("before first sleep")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("after first sleep")
    attempt(task)
    attempt(task)
    print("before second sleep")
    time.sleep(3) # Block CPU to wait for second sleeping to finish
    print("after second sleep")
    attempt(task)
    attempt(task)
    print(await asyncio.wrap_future(task))

asyncio.run(main())
```

### output

```
1.1 START 1
1.1 False
1.1 False
1.1 before first sleep
1.1 SETUP
3.1 MIDDLE
4.1 after first sleep
4.1 False
4.1 False
4.1 before second sleep
5.1 END
7.1 after second sleep
7.1 True
7.1 True
7.1 Result
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't want to run a second thread, though.  (Because then you need to start locking...) And I also don't want an asynchronous generator. I use the generator `send()` method, because that is how `async` methods/coroutines are implemented under the hood. I use it to try to "advance" the "underlying generator" that is the coroutine. But i don't need an `async` generator.

Comment: Without starting a second thread, what you are asking for is fundamentally impossible in python because there's no way you can have `await asyncio.sleep()` and `time.sleep()` executing concurrently on the same thread. You can only have multiple `await asyncio.sleep()` running concurrently in one thread.

Comment: I don't think `asyncio.sleep` is something that "executes", though. It doesn't do any work. It remembers the time and finishes if something tells it the time is reached. The `time.sleep` will prevent it from sleeping "accurately", but that is not the point. The `asyncio.sleep` is a placeholder for something that happens asynchronously, possibly in the OS. Like writing to a file or socket.

Comment: Yes, but the point still remains the same that you cannot run async concurrently with non-async code in the same thread (time.sleep / some other sync function), it may be an async network call or async run_in_executor or something else. 

Either your thread will be running the even loop -> which will give the interpreter bits of python code to run as tasks are done, or it can run just normal python code without an event loop. To run both you need 2 threads.

Answer (score 0):

I think I understood the problem now, and what makes this impossible. The main reason is the way the `asyncio.sleep` method is implemented:

- It gets the current running loop `loop = events.get_running_loop()`
- It creates a `Future` object with `loop.create_future()`
- Then it uses `loop.call_later(...)` to schedule a function that will resolve the future
- Then it awaits the created `Future`.

This means, that the future will only ever resolve, if the function that is scheduled with `call_later` is executed. There is no connection between the `Future` and the scheduled function.

When doing the second `send(None)` it will be send to the `FutureIter` object that the `sleep` method is awaiting. (`cr_await`)
But this object knows that the loop should have only ever called that method when the Future, it is waiting for, is resolved.

Because the event loop didn't have time to switch to the function that would resolve the future, it isn't resolved, yet. Which then results in the `RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future`.

And because there is no connection between the timed task and the Future that is found by looking at `coro.cr_await` there is no way to coerce the event loop to execute the task that will resolve the future and then allow the `sleep` function to advance.
The `FutureIter` does not even seem to expose it's internal `Future`, so there is no way to check if calling `send(None)` is save or not.

What makes this even worse is, that `await asyncio.sleep(0)` does not even seem to be enough to make sure that the `call_later` will be executed (Python 3.11.3):

```py
    task = asyncio.sleep(1)
    task.send(None)
    time.sleep(3)
    await asyncio.sleep(0) # Next send raises RuntimeError: await wasn't used with future
    # await asyncio.sleep(1) # Next send raises expected StopIteration
    try:
        task.send(None)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

So `attempt` has to be an `async` function and awaited and hope that the correct Tasks will be executed. But that would kind of defeat the whole point.

This previous method could maybe work if the coroutine that is used does not use the event loop itself and only ever awaits other non-event-loop coroutines. But that also defeats the point.

Very sad.

Answer (score 0):

The original problem can be solved using an approach similar to the implementation of `Task.__step` in the standard library.  I give a working example below.  I urge anyone who wants to use it to study the source code in `Task.__step` carefully.  A large number of possible exceptions and corner cases are handled there, all of which I cheerfully neglect in my simple demonstration.

The OP was on the right track when he attempted to drive the coroutine outside of the event loop, by calling `coro.send` rather than calling `asyncio.create_task`.  The `create_task` function turns the coroutine into a Task and schedules it for later execution.  The OP wants to run the coroutine immediately up to its first await expression - or at any rate, that's how I interpret his question.

The desired behavior can be achieved by calling `coro.step` exactly once, and then passing the coro object to `asyncio.create_task`.  The rest of the coroutine's functionality will be executed by asyncio in the normal way.  This avoids any need to re-implement the event loop functionality in its entirety.

Typically one calls `asyncio.create_task` on a "brand new" coroutine, but this is not a requirement.  The standard event loop drives coroutines by calling their `send` method repeatedly, and there is nothing special about the first such call.

A async def function (or coroutine) is very similar to a generator.  It implements the method `send`, and each call to `send` causes the coroutine to execute until it reaches the next `await` expression.  That suspends the coroutine and returns an object, in general one of two types: (1) `None`, or (2) an instance of `asyncio.Future`.

In the first case, the coroutine is ready to resume immediately, such as when it encountered this line of code:

```
await asyncio.sleep(0)
```

Handling this case is pretty straightforward: we can simply call `asyncio.create_task` and let asyncio take over.

In the second case, the coroutine should not be resumed until the Future is "done."  We cannot call `asyncio.create_task` yet, because the coroutine is waiting for something to happen.  We also cannot enter a tight loop to check the Future's status, because we must allow other code to use the thread in order to call the Future's `set_result` method.  The trick is to create a second Future that will become "done" when the first Future becomes done.

The following function, `task_launcher`, takes a coroutine object and returns a Future.  The coroutine is executed immediately up to its first await.  The result of the returned Future is the Task that was created.  The returned Future is *not* guaranteed to be "done," so in general it must itself be awaited at some point.

The rest of the program demonstrates its use.  The time stamps show that it's working.

```
import asyncio
import time

t0 = time.time()

def time_print(*args, **kwds):
    print(format(time.time() - t0,".3f"), *args, **kwds)

def task_launcher(cor):  # cor is a coroutine object
    """
    Return an asyncio.Future instance.  The result() of the
    returned Future is the task that was created.
    """
    # see tasks.py.__send for corner cases and more insights
    x = cor.send(None)
    if x is None:
        task = asyncio.create_task(cor)  # return a Task
        fut = asyncio.Future(loop=task.get_loop())
        fut.set_result(task)
        return fut
    if isinstance(x, asyncio.Future):
        fut2 = asyncio.Future()
        def cb(_a):
            task = asyncio.create_task(cor)
            fut2.set_result(task)
        x.add_done_callback(cb)
        return fut2
    raise ValueError(f"{cor} yielded the wrong kind of thing: {x}")

async def a_task():
    # An example of a task
    time_print("Step 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(5.0)
    time_print("Step 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
    time_print("Step 3")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.1)

async def b_task():
    # Another example of a task
    time_print("B Step 1")
    await asyncio.sleep(0.0)
    time_print("B Step 2")
    await asyncio.sleep(3.0)
    time_print("B Step 3")
    await asyncio.sleep(3.0)

async def main():
    fut_a = task_launcher(a_task())
    fut_b = task_launcher(b_task())
    time_print("Some other code")
    # fut_a and fut_b are futures, not tasks
    # To retrieve the task objects they must be awaited.  
    # I use gather() for that purpose but there are other possibilities.
    task_a, task_b = await asyncio.gather(fut_a, fut_b)
    # Now both tasks are started.  Wait for completion by calling
    # gather again.
    await asyncio.gather(task_a, task_b)  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Output:

```
0.000 Step 1
0.000 B Step 1
0.000 Some other code
0.000 B Step 2
3.002 B Step 3
5.001 Step 2
5.102 Step 3
```

I would say that actually using this approach is asking for trouble.  The idea behind this question was that there was some code that had to run *right now*, but that code was already written and was at the beginning of an async function.  Moving that code into a sync function and simply calling it would guarantee its immediate execution.  In my opinion this is the only correct approach.  My solution, though it works, depends on implementation details about the asyncio event loop.

Writing code that depends on implementation details was an unspoken aspect of the original question, which began by pointing out that Python is not Javascript - a truism that does not indicate any actual flaw in either language.

There were several misunderstandings in the original question.

- "Note that simply calling a coroutine will not schedule it to be executed. I find this very confusing."

Calling a coroutine *function* returns a coroutine *object*.  That object, like any other, can be passed to a function, put it a list, etc.  This is entirely consistent with Python's basic concepts.  If you want to do something with that object, you need to write more code, e.g., pass it to `asyncio.create_task`.  Also, asyncio supports cross-threaded program design, which involves creating a coroutine object in one thread and passing it to another for execution.  I don't see how this would be possible if the first call to a coroutine function also started its execution.

- "Asynchronous task happens in background . . . Only if await (or gather, etc.) is used is it actually started"

There is no such place as "background," no Emerald City where the Wizard magically executes your code for you.  Asyncio is a single-threaded cooperative multitasking paradigm, and `await` expressions are places where a Task switch can occur.  They are places where Tasks interact with the event loop.  They are the whole point, not an unfortunate necessity.

- "That makes it very hard to start a bunch of coroutines and wait for all of them or batches to finish, because if you use asyncio.gather they are all started at the very end and at the same time."

You can start a task any time you want, and in any order.  `Asyncio.gather` indeed will start them if they are not already started, but its main purpose is to wait for them to *finish*.

- `await asyncio.sleep(0)` somehow puts you "at the whim of the event loop."

It is true that this statement will not guarantee a particular order of task execution.  But you can rely on an entire cycle of the event loop to occur before the current routine will execute its next line of code.  In the meantime each Task that is ready will take exactly one step forward, i.e., will progress to the next await.

- (From the OP's "answer", his comments on asyncio.sleep call to Future.call_later) "There is no connection between the Future and the scheduled function."

One of the arguments to `call_later` is the Future itself.  There is indeed a connection.

The overall design of the event loop, combined with the implementation of Task.__step, ensures that all Futures get resolved or else produce error messages.  It is complex and cannot be understood just by looking at the implementation of `asyncio.sleep`.

Comment: The `task_launcher` is very similar to my `js_like_await`-decorator and only solves the starting, not resuming without `await`. If you use a method like `async def send()` and try to batch-send with `gather` your send-order depends on the order of arguments or the event loop and sending not started asap. Order is important. Can you see why this is bad?
Python makes it incredible hard to start a task without waiting for it to finish at the same time.
Of course there is a "background"-wizard. The operating system provides asynchronous IO operations that happen outside of the python-thread.

Comment: There is a reason the `StreamWriter.write()` method isn't `async`. But `async` is a leaky abstraction and spreads everywhere, even where it shouldn't. :/

The `Future` that is passed to `call_later` is an artifact of `asyncio.sleep`. Other Methods probably won't have their `Future` in the arguments, so you can't rely on that for determining which task resolves a Future.

Comment: Actually, I can't see why this is bad.  The idea of concurrent execution is that exact execution order is generally *unimportant*, and tasks (also threads and processes) are typically written so that's the case.  When order is important, synchronization primitives are available to enforce it.  I have been using asyncio extensively for years and I do not see any of this as a problem.  I also don't think that starting a task by writing `asyncio.create_task` is incredibly hard, but since you are so determined to hate Python there is not much I can say to convince you otherwise.

Comment: This isn't about concurrent execution, but asynchronous IO. (Which is pretty much the whole point of `async`, given that the package that contains all utilities for it is named `asyncio`) And for IO the order is very important. And it isn't just `asyncio.create_task`. Because your IO isn't scheduled if you don't force a context switch.
`ct=create_task; a=ct(send("A")); b=ct(send("B"); c=ct(send("C")); /* Calcualte something: Nothing is send yet*/; await gather(c, b, a)` Results in wrong order of sending. I don't hate Python. I'm sad it has these avoidable pitfalls because I love it.

Comment: If that code results in the wrong order of sending, it's because the `send` function is not written properly.  The `send` function does not have be declared `async def`, it only needs to return an awaitable object (so it can be passed as an argument to create_task).  The `send` function (a regular sync function) could start with all the procedural code necessary to start the IO process.  That code will execute immediately.  The returned value from that function could be a coroutine that can later be `await`ed for a result.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But it's way to easy to do it wrong, because adding `async` to a function is very easy and encouraged (e.g. because your `send()` might want to `await` something for post-processing).
A similar problem exists with reading: `lastRead = read(); while True { chunk = await lastRead(); lastRead = read(); np.matmul(something, chunk); }`. Does not do asynchronous reading. How do you teach people that they cannot make their functions `async` if they want asynchronous IO? JS avoids these problems by always executing the procedural code immediately. What is the benefit of NOT doing that?

Comment: And don't forget, that this is a layered problem. It might not exist in the python base library. Maybe its fixed in the custom library you are using (probably not). But to get all the benefits of asynchronous IO you have to fix this problem in EVERY layer of the callstack of a function/every wrapper function. This is unreasonable/unlikely and results in very ugly and hard to maintain code, because you loose a lot of the benefits of the `async`/`await` syntax while doing it.